# Arange `figures` from matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting auto-correlation graphs and partial auto-correlation graphs for 4 different countries.

My data is all together in a dataframe.

I pretty convenient/concise way to graph it is like this

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf
countries = ['Germany', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'US']
figs = df.query("Country_Region in @countries")\
         .groupby("Country_Region")['ConfirmedCases'].apply(plot_acf)
_ = [fig.suptitle(name) for fig, name in zip(figs, countries)]
```

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_pacf
countries = ['Germany', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'US']
figs = df.query("Country_Region in @countries")\
         .groupby("Country_Region")['ConfirmedCases'].apply(plot_pacf)
_ = [fig.suptitle(name) for fig, name in zip(figs, countries)]
```

As two separate lists of figures which doesn't look very nice in a notebook...

I know `subplots` are used to order axes for a single figure but I have multiple figures that I would like to arrange...

I think I'd have to re-implement what I'm doing to make it look pretty but I wanted to see if there's a convenient way to organize figures or I'd need to write something a lot more expressive to get what I want.

A good layout would look something like this

```
plot_acf(germany)      plot_pacf(germany)
plot_pacf(spain)       plot_pacf(spain)
plot_pacf(italy)       plot_pacf(italy)
plot_pacf(us)          plot_pacf(us)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "arrange"?  Arrange where?  Figures are separate windows or files - You can arrange them in a document using the document-creation software, just like you would any other image.  If you are asking to tile the windows, you'd need to tell us what backend you are using.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why not to use `subplots`?  You can pass an `axes` instance to `plot_acf` and should be easily able to create your desired output with that.

Comment: @Timo the only think I don't like about that is that I'd have to make a `for` loop to get it done, otherwise I wouldn't be able to specify which axis should receive what input at all... I think that's what I'm going to do, I just don't think it's elegant haha

Comment: @JodyKlymak I'm just working in Jupyter, It'd be nice to have them all display in the same cell side by side

Comment: You should just use a for-loop.  `plot_acf` accepts an axes as an argument.  s

Comment: @JodyKlymak You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up going for

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_pacf
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,2, figsize=(20,10))
for i, (country,data) in enumerate(df.query("Country_Region in ['Germany', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'US']").groupby("Country_Region")['ConfirmedCases']):
    plot_acf(data, ax=axes[i,0], title=country+" Autocorrelation")
    plot_pacf(data, ax=axes[i,1], title=country+" Autocorrelation")
fig.tight_layout()
```

(doesn't look good in dark mode but it's good enough if it's against a light background)

[image]